# Windows form, Which is a proper data structure definition for receiving/storing IDs and returning an integer?

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, events, data-structures

I'm building a windows Form app(I'm a newbie).

After an event is raised, I have to save the given object ID, store it and count the occurrence of it.

The ID is of a string type. Is like a serial number.

Which is a proper data structure definition for receiving/storing IDs and returning an integer(the occurrence of the object).
Do I need an array/dictionary that manage the storing and the count?

Comment: The ID of what *object*? What is the `ID`? Do you have a custom class object? Or is it a Control? Something else? Given the *ID*, do you need an object's reference back after? Of an existing object or a new instance? (...). The tool used to store these informations depends on the nature of the data and on what you want to do with it. Serialize it? Other?

Comment: So, a string? Or a Bitmap? Do you need to associate this ID with what other data? To do what with it? Provide details on the nature of this data and on the operations you need to perform.

Comment: The ID is kind of a serial number. So it should be a string type.It is associated with other data, but for the moment I have to manage only the IDs: From the event raising to the ID display together with the counter.

Comment: If it's just a `string` and an `int`, you can use a `Dictionary<string, int>`, where the ID (in the form of a string, if that is what it is) is the `Key` you use to retrieve the `Value`, the integer acting as a Counter. You might want to consider a `Dictionary<string, class>`, where `class` is a class object where you can store more informations about the object defined by a specific `ID`. Try to clarify what you need and what you want to do with it (e.g., store the info in a Database, serialize it to a `JSON` to send it over a Http/Tcp connection etc.) before choosing a specific storage tool.

Comment: yes the value should be more like a class/function. What I need to know is how to store the IDs, in order to display them later with the counter(through a simple GUI)

Comment: If with *how to store the IDs* you mean permanent storage - saving the data to Disc - it's a choice that depends on multiple factors. You could use a database, a JSON/XML file, User settings, configuration files etc. If you store your informations maily in class objects, you'll find it easier to store you data in any of these. You can serialize/deserialize a JSON with a couple of commands if you use a backing class structure (a model). A `Dictionary<string, class>` works well with both a Database and a JSON/XML, but also with configuration files.

Comment: It also depends on the nature of the data. If you have raw bytes (e.g., Bitmaps), a database is better. Otherwise, you have to Base64 encode the bytes. And so on.

Comment: I understand.Yeah, thank you for your help, so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Dictionary of object ID to count:

```
Dictionary<int,int> objectIds = new Dictionary<int,int>();
```

Then when you get an object id, add it if it doesn't exist or increment the count if it does:

```
if (objectIds.ContainsKey(objectId))
{
    objectIds[objectId]++;
}
else
{
    objectIds.Add(objectId, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either a List or array to store IDs, and then count occurance of IDs using linq query as shown below:

```
var listOfIds = new List<string> {"a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b"};
var query = from x in listOfIds
        group x by x into g
        let count = g.Count()
        orderby count descending
        select new {Value = g.Key, Count = count};

// Console.WriteLine is only used to show you how to access value and key inside your query
foreach (var x in q)
    Console.WriteLine("Value: " + x.Value + " Count: " + x.Count);
```